# How to modify Stored Procedure or ASP.net Code to get autogenerated Id after inserting new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I m creating new user registration moduleand for that i wrote following stored proc.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[addNewUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @usertype VarChar(10),
    @useremail VarChar(70),
    @userpass VarChar(20),
    @fullname VarChar(70),
    @city VarChar(70),
    @state Int,
    @allowAlerts Bit,
    @allowLetter Bit,
    @aboutMe NVARCHAR(160)

As
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


   if ((select count(user_info._id) from user_info where useremail like @useremail)  =  0)
    BEGIN
        Insert Into user_info
        (usertype,useremail,userpass,fullname,city,[state],allowAlerts,allowLetters,aboutMe)
           Values
           (
                @usertype,
                @useremail,
                @userpass ,
                @fullname,
                @city,
                @state,
                @allowAlerts,
                @allowLetter,
                @aboutMe
            )
        Select @@IDENTITY as NewID  
    END
    Else
    BEGIN
         Print '-1'         
    END
```

And following is the simple ASP.net C# Code that I try to use

```
 public int registerNewUser(string usertype, string useremail, string userpass, string fullname, string city, string state, string allowAlerts, string allowLetter, string aboutMe)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "addBlogEntry";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usertype", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usertype;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@useremail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = useremail;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userpass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userpass;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fullname;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = city;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt16(state);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@allowAlerts", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt16(allowAlerts);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@allowLetter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt16(allowLetter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@aboutMe", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aboutMe;
            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

                // some code to be written here so that i can return userID(success) or -1(if that username is already registered)
                 return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Through my C# code i want to return either auto generated userId which my stored procedures returns to me or if user alrady exists than i want to return -1

Please tell how to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ExecuteScalar() and change

```
Print '-1'
```

into

```
Select -1 as NewID
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` inside your stored proc to retrieve the new ID value (`@@IDENTITY` can return false results).

And yes, if you want to get the result back, you need to call either `.ExecuteScalar()` or `.ExecuteReader()` and then read that value back.

And while you're at it - I'd also recommend putting your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects into using blocks - so instead of your code, use this:

```
using(con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(cmd = new SqlCommand(con))
{
    ..... // put the rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an output parameter for your stored proc, and set it to the new key you can access it that way.  `ExecuteNonQuery` will return the number of rows affected, so that can be used as well.  Something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@uniquID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

// Your other code...

var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Your other code...

return (result == 1) ? (int)cmd.Parameters["@uniquID"].Value : -1;
```